# Why MySql connection not working on Flask Python API

Tags: python, mysql, flask-restful

I was using sqlite however moved to MySqL

Sqlite code that worked:

```
@app.route('/api/v1/users/user', methods=['GET'])
def api_filter():
    query_parameters = request.args
userid = query_parameters.get('userid')
username = query_parameters.get('username')

query = "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE"
to_filter = []

if userid:
    query += ' user_id=? AND'
    to_filter.append(userid)
if username:
    query += ' username=? AND'
    to_filter.append(username)
if not (userid or username):
    return page_not_found(404)

query = query[:-4] + ';'

conn = sqlite3.connect('dbApp.db')
conn.row_factory = dict_factory
cur = conn.cursor()

results = cur.execute(query, to_filter).fetchall()

return jsonify(results)
```

Now when I change it to MySQL it does not work:

```
@app.route('/api/v1/users/user', methods=['GET'])
def api_filter():
    query_parameters = request.args
userid = query_parameters.get('userid')
username = query_parameters.get('username')

query = "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE"
to_filter = []

if userid:
    query += ' user_id=? AND'
    to_filter.append(userid)
if username:
    query += ' username=? AND'
    to_filter.append(username)
if not (userid or username):
    return page_not_found(404)

query = query[:-4] + ';'

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="green", database="dbApp")
conn.row_factory = dict_factory
cur = conn.cursor()

results = cur.execute(query, to_filter).fetchall()

return jsonify(results)
```

The error returned:
results = cur.execute(query, to_filter).fetchall()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 260, in execute
raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Dec/2020 17:47:11] "

This is after running:
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/users/user?userid=3&username=Jo

http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/users/user?userid=3

http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/users/user?username=Jo

Also added this:
from flask import request, jsonify
import mysql.connector

Comment: You leaked your credentials above.   Do they work when you login with the mysql cli?

Comment: Hi @AllanWind , yes I can confirm I can, put them in another app and worked fine so scratching my head

Comment: What is line 260?

Comment: @AllanWind results = cur.execute(query, to_filter).fetchall()

Comment: It expects a tuple and you send it an array.

Comment: Can you try just hard-code ('some user',) to debug?

Comment: @AllanWind that gives me this: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'someuser' at line 1

Comment: Can you print the query and to_filter just before you execute it?

Comment: tuple(to_filter) should take care of the type if it maters (it may not).  Now we just need to verify that your query and bind parameter matches.

Comment: Brings back "null" when I execute:    results = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tblUser;")    #query, tuple(to_filter)).fetchall()

Could this be the problem: def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    d = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        d[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return d

Comment: What is #query?

Comment: @AllanWind thats just where I commented the line so I didn't lose it

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) says:

> cursor.execute(operation, params=None, multi=False)
> This method executes the given database operation (query or command).
> The parameters found in the tuple or dictionary params are bound to
> the variables in the operation. Specify variables using %s or %(name)s
> parameter style (that is, using format or pyformat style). execute()
> returns an iterator if multi is True.

I think there are two problems with your code: you are using ? for bind variables instead of %s, and you are passing in a list instead of a tuple.  Alternatively use named parameters and pass in the values with a dict. Try both and see what you like most.

1. `user_id = %s"` and `to_filter = (userid, )`.  You can use the list you have now and just convert it with `tuple()`.
2. `" user_id = %{user_id}"` and set `to_filter = {'user_id': userid }`.

It is cleaner to build a list of conditions, then ' AND '.join(conditions) instead of removing the extra `AND`.  You can simplify the code a little bit by just leaving out the ';'.